# Facebook Graph API Explorer will not show notifications

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications

I'm using https://graph.facebook.com/me/notifications/?include_read=1 but every time I use it the array shows up empty.

It says

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

I know I have read notifications.  I also have the manage_notification permission.

How can I see my notifications?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is like really old, but for future reference: You must use `?include_read=true` in order for this to work.